# How ubuntu implements Semaphore

Tags: bash, kernel, updates, scripts

How it works. I mean what is workflow of semaphore? I don't understand when in multiprocessor two process try to execute same line of code or same portion of memory then how ubuntu prevents it exactly? I know what is semaphore and technique used in its implementation. But how it exactly work. When OS finds such two process which file or which or how it starts its prevention and alongwith that what workflow comes out. Please I need to know it.

Comment: The operating system does not prevent it. It is the programmer's responsibility to take care that shared variables or files are accessed in a correct way.

Comment: But sir their are lots of files related to semaphore like sem_init,semaphore.h etc so how kernel actually work with them ?

Comment: The programmer who wishes to use [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) to synchronize the access to shared resources by two or more threads in their application will `#include <semaphore.h>` in their program and use them by calling the functions `sem_init()`, `sem_wait()`, `sem_post()` etc. Semaphores are implemented by the kernel; you can trust that they are implemented correctly. See the [Unreliable Guide to Locking](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/index.html) for an introduction to the implementation.

Comment: Thankyou sir Can you suggest me some links or books related to implementation of semaphore in ubuntu so that I can further polish my concept and become able to impllement semaphore in kernel.

Comment: See the Kernel Newbies community, [https://kernelnewbies.org/](https://kernelnewbies.org/).